# setTimeout inside a loop gives all the iterations at once

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
myList = [["one", "two", "three"], ["uno", "dos", "tres"], ["1","2","3"]]    

    myList.forEach(function (subList) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(subList);
        }, 5000);
    });
```

I think that every 5 seconds, this should output each of the elements of `myList`, however, rather than iterating it just waits five seconds and then outputs the three sub lists at once.

How can I do it, so it does a sublist, then wait 5 sec, then next one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to do

```js
myList = [["one", "two", "three"], ["uno", "dos", "tres"], ["1","2","3"]]    

    myList.forEach(function (subList, i) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(subList);
        }, 5000*(i+1));
    });
```

since

```
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(subList);
    }, 5000);
```

means that it will print subList after at least 5000ms, all events are called after 5000ms

> 5000*(i+1) will ensure that it is called after 5000ms, 10000ms, 15000ms...

Comment: Ok, so you are saying that the "counter" doesn't reset on every iteration? I thought that if you iterate inside the `forEach`, every time you put a setTimeout, the 5000 counter should start from zero...

Comment: Mind that this will 'schedule' all functions at once. This might work for you, but it depends on the desired behavior.

Comment: yes every counter starts from 0